# Перенаправить с адреса включающего порт на поддомен

Tags: apache, node.js, nginx

Здравствуйте,
Есть 3 веб-сервера nginx, apache, nodejs работающих на портах 80, 8080 и 8090 соответственно. Подскажите есть ли возможность запретить обращение к ним напрямую через указание порта и дать возможность обратиться через поддомен.
Например:
http://localhost:80 заменить на http://nginx.localhost;
http://localhost:8080 заменить на http://apache.localhost;
http://localhost:8090 заменить на http://nodejs.localhost;

Comment: Если IP у сервака только один, а не 3, то такие запросы _обязаны_ пройти через 80 порт, там Nginx, он вроде умный, по идее может в качестве прокси перебросить трафик на другие web-сервисы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно вы правильно рассуждаете `127.0.0.1:80` это локальная петля и видна только локально. Указать любой домен и `listen 80` - это будет публичный сервер

```
server {
  listen 127.0.0.1:80;
}

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name public.mydomain;
}
```

а также регулировать и определять доступ через proxy nginx

```
server {
   listen 8080;  
   location / {
     proxy_pass http://backend;
     // ...
   }
}
```

То есть все серверы будут работать на `127.0.0.1` например, а доступ будет через прокси nginx. Это "один из" и очень простой и надежный вариант. Вы всегда сможете спокойно изменять адреса и порты серверов, но фронт-сервер при этом изменяться не будет.